# Remove ion tabs border ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

In ionic new version from 4 we can remove border of tabs by adding

```
ion-tab-bar {
        border: 0;
        margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Comment: ion-tab-bar {
        border: 0;
        margin-top: -1px;
}

Answer (score 1):

Add scss

```
:host {
       ion-tab-bar {
        border: 0;
        margin-top: -1px;
      }
}
```